# Simulate Writing to stdin()

Tags: r, io, prompt

Some R GUIs (e.g. RStudio) display terminal input differently to normal output (e.g. in blue in RStudio).  I'm looking to simulate this behavior by leveraging the same mechanism as `readline` does.  In other words, I want to be able to trick R into thinking that some expression is coming from the terminal. Something like:

```
cat("hello", file=stdin())
```

which of course doesn't work since `stdin` is r only.  `readline` is able to do this, but unfortunately it also requires the user to type something, which I want to avoid (ideally, I want the non-interactive `readline` behavior).

Looking at the source code, it seems that the behavior I want is implemented by `R_ReadConsole` and `R_WriteConsole` C functions in `\src\gnuwin32\system.c` (on my windows machine), themselves called by `ConsoleGetChar` in `src\main\scan.c`, but I don't think I can call this directly from R.  I also can't see a way to force `readline` to think it's running in non-interactive mode.

I do not want to colorize the text directly with escape character sequences.  I want the colorization to be handled by the GUI the same way it does for terminal input (i.e. presumably by reading `stdin` and outputing the contents colorized) so that the implementation is OS/GUI independent.

I would like to do this without writing C code. Is this possible?